# Populate select from javascript on dropdown action

Tags: javascript

I want to put an empty select on an html page.
When the users clicks on this select, I want to load items from a web service.
I did manage to make it work with a bootstrap button but not with a basic html select.

Comment: "*I want X*" is not a question.

Comment: Any luck with the suggested solutions?

Comment: no, no luck i had to do it with a custom dropdown with div, ul and li tags. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

There is very little information to go on from your question... But generally you could use an AJAX call to dynamically fill in the options.

```
$("select").click(function(){
    $.getJSON(url, function(data){
        options = JSON.parse(data);
        $.each(options, function(index, value){
            $("<option/>").appendTo("select").val(value).append(value);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very similar solution to the one [CodeAt30](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2253052/codeat30) suggested, but without the jQuery dependency:

```js
// fake web service
const getSelectOptions = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve(['option 1','option 2', 'option 3', 'option 4']);
});

const populateWithOptions = () => {
  //abort if select box has already been populated
  if(document.querySelector('#s1 option')) return;
  
  const selectElement = document.querySelector('#s1');
  getSelectOptions().then(options => {
    options.forEach(option => {
      const optionElement = document.createElement('option');
      optionElement.value = option;
      optionElement.innerHTML = option;
      selectElement.appendChild(optionElement);
      }
     );
  });
};

const handleSelect = () => {
  const selectElement = document.querySelector('#s1');
  alert('user selected ' + selectElement.value);
}

window.populateWithOptions = populateWithOptions;
window.handleSelect = handleSelect;
```

```html
<div>
  <select id="s1" onmouseover="populateWithOptions()" onclick="populateWithOptions()" onchange="handleSelect()">
  </select>
</div>
```